# Compiling an external website to .chm using wget

Tags: html, wget, chm

There's a website, in particular http://thisquantumworld.com

It is a text-only site with inter-related links. I want to have the content on this site as reading material. I can(and I did) download the site as html using wget.

But, it would be good to have it as a .chm file. In that case, it will be easily redistributable too.

**Can anyone suggest a way to download a website as .chm(maybe using wget)?** I have no experience with .chm files and have no idea how do they work.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help

Comment: @MarcB Helpful comment, but doesn't answer my question!

Comment: You could try chmcmd 
http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmcmd in combination with wget

Comment: @sine I'll try that and mention the results.

Answer (score 0):

For such purpose (convert web-site to chm), I use Windows freeware tool [Web2Chm](http://webtochm.converterfreeware.com/my/web2chm-setup.exe).

It works perfectly, and I almost sure - it will work under the Wine in Linux too.

If you want to use only wget, I think your task can be solved using python scripts.